# Unknown behaviour when mantissa is larger than 23 bits?

Tags: ieee-754

Why does -673.4 in IEEE-754 end with 10 and not 01?

Sign bit is 1.

Converted to binary it is: 1010100001.01100110011001100110011001100110...

Exponent is 136=10001000

So shouldn't full number be: 1 10001000 01010000101100110011001

Instead by calculators I get: 1 10001000 01010000101100110011010

So why did last two bits change, and what is algorithm behind it (how can I calculate how and when do they change)?

Comment: The result is rounded, not simply truncated, and the bit following the last position is `1`. It's much the same as the reason why `673.39` would become `673.4` when rounded to one digit, and not `673.3`. With rounding, the exact value is `-673.4000244140625`; with truncating, we' d get `-673.39996337890625`, which is further away from the true value. The exact rules for how to convert a decimal representation of a number to the most accurate floating-point representation are complex, which is why it's fortunate that libraries implement this already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number given by calculators converts back to decimal as `-673.4000244140625`, or 24.4 millionths too high.

The number you propose as the "proper" encoding converts back as `-673.3999633789062`, or 36.6 millionths too low.

They're both very close to the number you wanted, but the uexpected one is marginally closer.

[IEEE rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Rounding_rules) usually rounds to the nearest number, although the scheme you imagined, "truncation" or round towards zero, is also defined and used in some devices or applications.